# I cant seem to find the error in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new at meteor and I am having some issues. I am creating a social network app and what it basically does is signs up user and the user can post and follow others. Thats the basic functionality it does right now. I want to add something that when a user clicks on other users profile it shows that users post. But the code isnt working and doesnt show any error at all

Template

```
<template name="profileArea">
{{#if currentUser}}
    <div id="side-profile"  class="side-box">
        <a class="filter-user">{{currentUser.username}}</a>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    <div id="side-all"  class="side-box">
        <a class="community">Community</a>
    </div>
    {{#if currentUser}}
    <div id="side-like"  class="side-box">
      <h3>Following</h3>
      <div class="boxcontent">
        {{#each username in following}}
           <div>
              <a class="filter-user">{{username}}</a>
           </div>
        {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
      <div id="side-likeyou" class="side-box">
        <h3>Follows You</h3>
      <div class="boxcontent">
        {{# each followers}}
            <div>
                <a class="filter-user">{{username}}</a>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Code:

```
Template.profileArea.events({
    'click .filter-user': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var selectedUser = event.target.text;

        Session.set('username', selectedUser);
    },
    'click .community': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        Session.set('username', null);
    }
});

Template.postsList.helpers({
    posts: function() {
        //Stuff should happen here but its not -_-
        var result;
        if(Session.get('username')){
            result = Post.find({username: Session.get('username')}, {sort:{created: -1}});
        }
        else{
           result = Post.find({}, {sort:{created: -1}});
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: Where in your template are you rendering the sub-template `postsList`? Your example does not include this detail.

Comment: Hi is this what you mean?

<template name="postsList">
  <ul class="post-list">
    {{#each posts}}
    <li class="posts">
    <div>{{content}}</div>
    <div>{{username}}<a class="follow-link">Follow</a></div>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this case is that you have never actually rendered your `postsList` template (you have only just defined it).

If you want to actually see `postsList` you need to call `{{> postsList }}` from somewhere in your `profileArea`'s HTML.  This will render that template and then your `postsList.posts` helper will execute (and change reactively when `Session.get('username')`) changes.

Maybe add this after the 'Follows You' section of the profile.

```
<div id="side-posts" class="side-box">
  <h3>Posts</h3> 
  <div class="boxcontent"> {{> postsList }} <div>
</div>
```